# Create a Special Widget with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

[image]

I have a design figma, when I scroll it's like a list view, the line below the middle one gets smaller, and from right to left it gets bigger. I want to create a widget as same as.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Please help me, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- For the whole project, the widget you asked should wrapped with AnimatedList.
- For the hour / weather zone. You can use animatedPositioned widget and also you have to listen the scroolController value for slowly animate hour / weather zone to front.
- Lastly the bottom scroller. Basically use an animatedList again with AnimatedContainer children. Create a method to control length of list you requested. Looks like you are creating 7 containers per hour / weather zone.
- For each display ( hour / weather ) you are animating 5 containers. Just listen the animatedList's index and controller AnimatedContainers height property.